# How to save a DataFrame from Spark to Cassandra table by changing the schema and adding additional properties

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have used Spark SQL to retrieve data from a Cassandra database:

```
DataFrame customers = sqlContext.cassandraSql("SELECT email, first_name, last_name FROM customer " +
                "WHERE CAST(store_id as string) = '" + storeId + "'");
```

After that I did some filtration and I want to save this data into another Cassandra table that looks like this:

```
store_id uuid,
report_name text,
report_time timestamp,
sharder int,
customer_email text,
count int static,
firts_name text,
last_name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((store_id, report_name, report_time, sharder), customer_email)
```

How can I add these additional properties when I save the `DataFrame` into the new table? Also what is the best practice to shard the Cassandra long row using this example? I expect to have 4k-6k records in the `DataFrame`, so sharding the long row is a must, but I am not sure if counting the records and then changing the `sharder` for a certain number of items is the best practice in Spark or Cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you have the DataFrame, you can define a case class, which has the structure of the new schema with the added properties.

You can create the case class like this: `case class DataFrameRecord(property1: String, property2: Long, property3: String, property4: Double)`

Then you can use map to convert into the new structure using the case class: `df.rdd.map(p => DataFrameRecord(prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4)).toDF()`

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like that. I don't know if creating a new class for every record will be an overhead.

Comment: Hm, I know only one alternative method, which is also mentioned in the spark doku: creating a new schema based on original rdd and a new structType. You can have a look at it in the doku here: [Spark Doku](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema). But I am not sure, which method has the best performance. Actually I only know those two methods of changing the rdd/df schema. Maybe you could do a measurment of both and also tell me, which one is faster :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some sort of [transformation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) (like `map()`) to add the properties to the data frame.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Greg. Can you give me an example? I have no idea how to do this. Everything I've tried so far does not work.

Comment: AlexL's answer is an example of what I was referring to. Instantiating a case class per record is a common convention for data frames.